# Notation of the partial derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

What does in simple word this notation means: $$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right) dx $$

I understand it this way: the rate of change of $u$ with respect to $x$. But what we achieve by multiplying partial derivative by $dx$ afterwards?

Comment: Hint : think of the single variable calculus where you used to write the change in $y-$axis as $dy= f'(x)dx$, where $f'(x)$ means the rate at which function increases or decreases with respect to $x$, and multiplying it with the small distance $dx$ gives you that total increment or decrement in $y$, which we write as $dy$.

Comment: Now the only change here is that $u$ depends on more than one variable, and so we used the partial notations, which essentially means the same thing, it is rate of change of the function with respect to change in $x-$coordinate, and when you multiply the distance moved along $x-$axis, it gives the resultant change in $u$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think now I understood the meaning of this notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on the context. If $u$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ and $x$ and $y$ are in turn functions of $t$, then $u$ is a function of $t$ and the chain rule states $$\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac {\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt}.$$ This can be abbreviated as the differential $$du = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} dx + \frac {\partial u}{\partial y} dy$$ which contains in part the expression you are asking about. In simple terms you can approximate the increment in the function $u$ in terms of the increments of both $x$ and $y$ individually if you know the values of the partial derivatives of $u$. Specifically it is a convenient way of expressing the linear approximation to $u$: $$u(x,y) - u(x_0,y_0) \approx \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) (x-x_0) + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0) (y-y_0).$$